# package rgrs define carte.qual colour palette

Tags: r, color-palette

I'm using the rgrs package to creat a qualitative based map. I'm not a fan of the palettes provided by ColorBrewer, how can I define my own colour palette?

I tried the following...

```
pal<-c("#2ca25f","#99d8c9","#99d8c9")

carte.qual(Frdep, Corr, "Niveau_correlation", sp.key = "CODE_DEPT", 
       data.key = "Dep", 
       palette.qual="pal", border="grey25", 
       leg.options=list(rect.width=0.025, rect.height=0.045, 
                        inset=c(0.68, 0.345), cex=0.85))
```

Which returns the following error message:

```
Error in brewer.pal(qual.nb, palette.qual) : 
pal is not a valid palette name for brewer.pal
```

Removing the speech marks from "pal" returns the same message. Can anyone help?

Comment: Try using the `palette` argument instead of palette.qual, also, don't quote `pal`. So `cart.qual(...,palette=pal)`

Comment: I'll just convert that to an answer if it worked for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using the `palette.qual` when you should be using the `palette` argument. Your code should read:

```
pal<-c("#2ca25f","#99d8c9","#99d8c9")

carte.qual(Frdep, Corr, "Niveau_correlation", sp.key = "CODE_DEPT", 
       data.key = "Dep", 
       palette=pal, border="grey25", 
       leg.options=list(rect.width=0.025, rect.height=0.045, 
                        inset=c(0.68, 0.345), cex=0.85))
```